# SAPUI5 - Update View

Tags: javascript, sapui5

So I am navigating from one page to another called "chart" with the following line:

`this.getRouter().navTo("chart");`

The first time I visit the page the content is updated. 
Do I go there the second time via the code the onInit() and the other standard functions are not called. I tested it with an alert() in each.
How can I create a function that updates my view every time the page is visited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
```

triggers when your route is matched

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can `destroy()` your view each time you navigate off it. And create it when navigating to it. This way your `onInit()` and other functions which are called on start up, will be called and executed.

Your `onInit()` and other standard functions are not called when you navigate to the view for the second time because the view is already rendered.